# Object filter by N highest numeric values (of keys)

Tags: javascript

### Demo Object:

```
var foo = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6, g:7}
```

### Wanted result: (get top 3 keys by value)

```
{e:5, f:6, g:7}
```

---

#### Explanation:

For a given key/value basic object, how would you get the 3 top values, but not just the values but also the keys? keys could be anything. lets say values are integers.

performance should be in mind.

Comment: Reading this now, I can't seem to understand my own question :) what was I thinking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get key/value pairs:

```
let pairs = Object.entries(foo);
```

Sort them:

```
pairs.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
```

Turn some back into an object:

```
let result = Object.fromEntries(pairs.slice(-3));
```

Answer (score 11):

You can extract the properties into an array, then sort the array:

```
var foo = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6, g:7}
var props = Object.keys(foo).map(function(key) {
  return { key: key, value: this[key] };
}, foo);
props.sort(function(p1, p2) { return p2.value - p1.value; });
var topThree = props.slice(0, 3);
```

If you want the result as an object, just reduce it back to one

```
var topThreeObj = props.slice(0, 3).reduce(function(obj, prop) {
  obj[prop.key] = prop.value;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

Comment: For completeness: `Object.keys` will only retrieve enumerable properties. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` can be used to retrieve non-enumerable ones too.