# JavaScript : Extract properties from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, object

**Problem statement :** I am having a JSON object contains `n` number of properties inside it. I need to pass some properties from this JSON object as a JSON string to the server.

**Tried :** I used [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method to make the `enumerable` as `false` of the object properties that I don't want to pass in my `JSON string`. Please find below the code snippet to get more clear picture.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "name": "Rohit",
  "age": 27,
  "city": "Gurgaon"
};

Object.defineProperty(jsonObj, 'name', {
  enumerable: false
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
```

**Problem facing with above code :**

Suppose i have a `100` number of properties in an object and i want to pass only `20` properties to the server out of `100`. Then i have to write below line of code `80` times to remove the unwanted properties and it will affect the performance of the application.

```
Object.defineProperty(jsonObj, 'name', { enumerable: false });
```

I also looked into already asked questions on SO but did not find any suitable answer for this problem statement.

- [Pick random property from a Javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532218/pick-random-property-from-a-javascript-object)
- [get top N values' keys of an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302234/get-top-n-values-keys-of-an-object)

Is there any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: How do you decide which properties to send to the server? Do you have an array of property names?

Comment: Did you compare if it wouldn't be faster to send the whole object to the server?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is always the option to create a new object and only pull out the keys you need. See [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25553910/218196) for that.

---

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) accepts a "replacer" function as second argument. That allows you to change values during serialization, including filtering them out. Assuming there are fewer properties that you want to keep, you should list those in an array or `Set`.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "name": "Rohit",
  "age": 27,
  "city": "Gurgaon"
};
var toKeep = ['age', 'city']; 

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  jsonObj,
  (key, value) => !key || toKeep.indexOf(key) > -1 ? value : undefined,
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new object you want to send to server

My solution:

```
var jsonObj = {
  "name": "Rohit",
  "age": 27,
  "city": "Gurgaon"
};

// if you don't need specific keys you should delete this and ~keys.indexOf(prop) in condition
var keys = ['name', 'city', 'moscow'];

function newObj(obj, count) {
  var newObj = {};
  var counter = count;

  for (var prop in obj) {
    if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && ~keys.indexOf(prop)) {
      newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
      counter -= 1;
    }

    if(counter === 0) break;
  }

  return newObj;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj(jsonObj, 20)));
```

Comment: `for...in` can iterate over properties in arbitrary order, so this would pick 20 random properties?

Comment: @FelixKling, I dont understand your question

Comment: I guess I should turn it into a statement: this solution will select 20 arbitrary properties, which doesn’t seem to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @FelixKling, And now? I changed the code :) do you like?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "name": "Rohit",
  "age": 27,
  "city": "Gurgaon"
};

var newObj = jsonObj;
var arr = ["name","age"];

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  delete newObj[arr[i]]
}

console.log(newObj);
```

This may solve your problem I feel.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following , It will not modify your original object:

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "name": "Rohit",
  "age": 27,
  "city": "Gurgaon"
};
var storePropeties = ["city"];
var result = Object.keys(jsonObj).reduce(function (obj, key) {
   if(storePropeties.includes(key))
      obj[key] = jsonObj[key];
     return obj
 }, {})

console.log(result);
```